# Serializing a .NET class doesn't save Color

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization, colors

VB2012 I have a class which I am serializing to a file as such

```
Dim fileXml As String = "C:\out.xml"
swXml = New StreamWriter(fileXml)
Dim serXml As New XmlSerializer(nzp.GetType)
serXml.Serialize(swXml, nzp)
```

This all works great except there is one field that is a System.Drawing.Color and that doesn't get saved. Does serialization only work for basic types? How do I get the framework to save more complex types?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376234/best-solution-for-xmlserializer-and-system-drawing-color

Comment: Thanks. That gave me the idea of saving it as a string in HTML spec. Then I just convert to HTML and then from HTML. It works.

Comment: XmlSerializer does not operate on fields.  I assume you meant property.