# System Color in an object class field

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am creating an object class from an XML file and then would like to assign one field which is not int the XML file, namely: `Color`.

My serialization is as follows:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class pack
{
    public steps steps { get; set; }           
}

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class steps
    {
        readonly ChildCollection<step> Steps;           

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("step")]
        public Collection<step> StepList { get { return Steps; } } 
    }
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class step
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("step")]
    public Collection<step> StepList { get { return Steps; } }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("Color")]
    public System.Drawing.Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

As you see, in the last line from the code I am creating a color field and then in the other function will assign some variable color for that.

```
pack XmlFilePack = new pack();
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"Steps_1.xml"))
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(pack));
        XmlFilePack = (pack)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
    finally
    {
        //close file
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

But I have always `null` for the `XmlFilePack`. Does anyone know where is the error?

**Update**: Here is the XML file:

```
<pack >
    <steps>
        <step id ="12" name="S1" >
        </step>
        <step id ="1" name="S1" >
            <step id ="2" name="S11" >
                <step id ="3" name="S111" >
                    <step id ="5" name="S1121" >
                    </step>
                </step>
            </step>
            <step id ="6" name="S12" >              
                <step id ="4" name="S112" >
                    <step id ="14" name="S112" >
                    </step>
                </step>     
            </step>
        </step>
    </steps>
</pack>
```

Comment: Does it work without `Color` property? What is in the file?

Comment: Yes it does work very nicely

Comment: `System.Drawing.Color` cannot be serialized out of the box by `XmlSerializer`.  For alternatives see [Most elegant xml serialization of Color structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280362).

Comment: Show us xml node `Color`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I have added the XML file. I would like to mention that ther is no `Color` node in XML file and I am creating just inside serialization for the usage in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Drawing.Color` class doesn't play well with serialization. What I've found is that it's often best to wrap classes like this as described, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376234/best-solution-for-xmlserializer-and-system-drawing-color).

Basically converting the `Color` to the equivalent HTML value for serialization

```
String HtmlColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(MyColorInstance);
```

but wrapped in a class.

Comment: But I am not working with HTML. Mein is GUI and will be ok?

Comment: Use the ColorTranslator to convert it back to a Color class when deserializing the XML.

Comment: @Saber if it worked for you, consider marking as accepted to help others know that it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I found another solution as I have written as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers and comments. I found out the following answer will work, too:

I defined `Color` as a `string`

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("Color")]
public string Color { get; set; }
```

and then wrote this code

```
System.Drawing.Color colstep1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(xNode.Color);
var col1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(xNode.Color);
childTreeNode.ForeColor = col1;
```

It works very nice and easy somehow to manage.